# Android Studio update (1.5 to 2.2.3) breaks project

Tags: android-studio, gradle, import, updates, libraries

So i've updated my Android Studio from Version 1.5 to 2.2.3 and this completely broke my project. I'm pretty new at programming and my app worked just fine before, but now, every single android library import is marked red.

```
import android.animation.ArgbEvaluator;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
```

for example, none of these are recognized any more. I've updated everything Android Studio wanted me to, but tbh i don't know how to fix this.

My gradle file looks like the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.privatpc.quiztest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

}
```

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.


buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Update:**
Doing File-> "Invalidate Caches/Restart" seemed to work. Now the next Problem is the following:

Once i try running the project the app opens and immediately crashes. I get the following log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project?

Comment: yes, but there was no change. File-> "Invalidate Caches/Restart" seemed to work though, as there are no more errors now before runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this in build.gradle

buildscript {repositories {jcenter()}dependencies {classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'}}

Comment: I updated the questions with the build.gradle, it was already in there. Also the imports are recognized now, though there seems to be another problem with the appcompat theme that i don't understand

Comment: Change the Java inheritance from ActionBarActivity to Activity and try

Comment: Where exactly do i have to do this? My class extends AppCompatActivity?

Comment: Ya change that to Activity and try please

Comment: ok  try this,Add this attribute to your activity
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"

Comment: Its k happy to help

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying on devices below Android 7, generate APK by using V1 signature instead of V2. All apps will crash if you select V2 Signature because it is targeting for Android 7.

[signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqEN2.png)